# Using Ecto for Postgres fulltext search on GIN indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing, full-text-search, elixir, ecto

I have a simple model:

```
schema "torrents" do
  field :name, :string
  field :magnet, :string
  field :leechers, :integer
  field :seeders, :integer
  field :source, :string
  field :filesize, :string

  timestamps()
end
```

And I want to search based on the name. I added the relevant extensions and indexes to my database and table.

```
def change do
  create table(:torrents) do
    add :name, :string
    add :magnet, :text
    add :leechers, :integer
    add :seeders, :integer
    add :source, :string
    add :filesize, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  execute "CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;"
  execute "CREATE INDEX torrents_name_trgm_index ON torrents USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);"

  create index(:torrents, [:magnet], unique: true)
end
```

I'm trying to search using the search term, **but I always get zero results**.

```
def search(query, search_term) do
  from(u in query,
  where: fragment("? % ?", u.name, ^search_term),
  order_by: fragment("similarity(?, ?) DESC", u.name, ^search_term))
end

SELECT t0."id", t0."name", t0."magnet", t0."leechers", t0."seeders", t0."source", 
t0."filesize", t0."inserted_at", t0."updated_at" FROM "torrents" 
AS t0 WHERE (t0."name" % $1) ORDER BY similarity(t0."name", $2) DESC ["a", "a"]
```

Is something wrong with my search function?

Comment: Do you get any errors logged in the console? I can't seem to find what the `%` means in `WHERE (t0."name" % $1)` in PostgreSQL docs.

Comment: @Dogbert No errors, just the proper SQL command output. I got the commands from this article: http://blog.rokkincat.com/postgres-full-text-search-in-ecto/

Comment: What records do you have in the table? Note that your query will not match every record whose name contains `a` but records with names that are sufficiently similar. Try creating a record with name `"a"` and run the same query. Or create `"ab"` and `"abc"` and search for `"ab"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial guess is that because you're using the `%` operator, the minimum limit to match is too high for your queries. This limit defaults to `0.3` (meaning that the strings' trigrams are 30% similar).  If this threshold isn't met, no results will be returned.

If that is the issue, this threshold is configurable in a couple of ways.  You can either use `set_limit` (docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-FUNC-TABLE)), or set the limit on a per query basis.

The `set_limit` option can be a bit of a hassle, as it needs to be set per connection every time.  Ecto (through db_connection) has an option to set a callback function for `after_connect` (docs [here](https://hexdocs.pm/db_connection/DBConnection.html#start_link/2)).

To change the limit per query, you can use the `similarity` function in the where clause, like this:

```elixir
def search(query, search_term, limit = 0.3) do
  from(u in query,
  where: fragment("similarity(?, ?) > ?", u.name, ^search_term, ^limit),
  order_by: fragment("similarity(?, ?) DESC", u.name, ^search_term))
end
```

To start, I would try that with a limit of zero to see if you get any results.

Comment: Should the function signature be instead: `def search(query, search_term, limit \\ 0)` ?

Comment: Searches are taking around 2 seconds, is that normal? Shouldn't it be much faster? I have around 1.5 million records.

Comment: If you are using a limit of 0 with a `search_term` that matches many rows, it will have to order all of those rows (potentially hundreds of thousands or even millions), which may not be fast.